# Javascript RegEx: validate date time

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, date, time

I am not very good with regex. I am being frustrated by a regular expression.

Example:

I have the following date time: 05/16/2013 12:00 am

I need a javascript regex that respect this format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm [am/pm]

```
 var dateReg = /^[0,1]?\d{1}\/(([0-2]?\d{1})|([3][0,1]{1}))\/(([1]{1}[9]{1}[9]{1}\d{1})|([2-9]{1}\d{3}))$/;
if(!dateReg.test(inputVal)) {
    $(this).after('<span class="error error-keyup-5">Invalid date format.</span>');
}
```

But this code works only for date, not with time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want your date to be valid for each country? So for example 16/5/2013 12:00 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippet does only match the date, there are no atoms to match the time.  Your regexp should be:

```
dateReg = /^[0,1]?\d\/(([0-2]?\d)|([3][01]))\/((199\d)|([2-9]\d{3}))\s[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (am|pm)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

A regexp for am/pm time can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820372/regex-for-am-pm-time-format-for-jquery):

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][mM]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be parsing dates and times yourself. Find a good library to do it. d3.js contains fine support for parsing dates and times according to formats you specify. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting.