# Validating Date of birth signup calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, date

I need to validate my birth dates in my signup form a valid date must not be in the future, and no non-existent dates e.g 31 june is there an easy way to do this without coding for each month?

Comment: jQuery Date Picker . or HTML5  `type="date"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this manually.. This code should suffice (I'm pretty sure the pattern supports `dd/mm/yyyy`).

```
function checkDateTime(newDate) {
    var pattern = '^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$';
    var regex = new RegEx(pattern);

    if (typeof newDate === 'string' && newDate.trim().match(regex)) {
        var parsedDate = new Date(newDate);
        var today = new Date();
        if (parsedDate.getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
            //The date is valid...
        }
    }
}
```

- [validate datetime with javascript and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972728/validate-datetime-with-javascript-and-regex)
- [Check if a string is a date value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445328/check-if-a-string-is-a-date-value)
- [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)
- [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: thank you for the answer I eventually coded the entire thing manually using javascript it was relatively easy since there are only 7 months that end on the 31st in a year

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery datepicker you can use this code:

```
$("#born_date").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    maxDate: '+0d', 
    yearRange: '-90:+0',
    numberOfMonths: 1
});
```

Best regards!

Comment: I prefer to use the old selectbox format and validate the form data than a plugin I just need the code to validate a selectbox with a day, month and year field

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript in combination with html5 validation pattern:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/[0-9]{4}"
 onchange="this.className = Date.parse(this.value) < Date.now() && 'valid'">
```

Find more patterns here:
http://html5pattern.com/Dates

If someone

Comment: thanx I'll use this in my other projects