# Best solution for call angular.isDate()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check my type of variable, is it date. I want use angular.isDate() function.

If my variable have value "2016-08-10T08:38:49.397" angular.isDate() return false, what i can do?

```
<div ng-app="autoDrops" ng-controller="testController">
      {{isDate(date)}}
<div>

var autoDrops = angular.module('autoDrops', []);
autoDrops.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.date = '2016-08-10T08:38:49.397'
    $scope.isDate = function(value){
        return angular.isDate(value);
    }
});
```

Example is on the ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5bL5tfo5/16/))

Comment: `isDate` checks if the value is literally *an instance of `Date`*, not a string which can be interpreted as a date…

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't just be doing this in the controller? Do you specifically want to show the result on the screen? in which case I would still keep the logic in the controller and just present the result through a controller property.

Comment: I know, but what is best solution for this problem, when you have datetime in string?

Comment: Try [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20972863/427146), you have to edit the regex though. It circumvents the usual pitfalls of leapyear dates and invalid dates which might be parsed into valid dates.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.isDate` literally checks if the given value is an instance of `Date`. If you want to *parse a string* to see whether it contains a value that can be interpreted as date, use `Date.parse`:

```
> Date.parse('woeriug')
< NaN
> Date.parse('2016-08-10T08:38:49.397')
< 1470818329397
```

However, [as MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Parsing of strings with `Date.parse` is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

If you want more dependability, use a third party library that implements robust and browser-independent date parsing (or do it yourself).

Comment: If I use Date.parse I don't need angular.isDate because we can write code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5bL5tfo5/30/)

Comment: Yup. You should not depend on Angular for handling dates, that's not what it's for.

Comment: problem in date.parse it is when you pass number, this function return valid date [example](https://jsfiddle.net/5bL5tfo5/31/).  This not good decision.

Comment: So what *do* you accept as a valid date and what don't you? Again, if you need more options and flexibility than Javascript offers you by default, there are many robust date parsing/handling/formatting/converting libraries out there.