# Regex expression to match the case AM/PM of time "12:30PM"

Tags: javascript, regex

Here i have a time which is in the format of hh:mma . AM/PM are not separated using white space with time.Now how to use regex to get the AM/pm and the time using javascript.

Comment: Do you have a string containing just that time format or the string contain more stuff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for AM PM time format for jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820372/regex-for-am-pm-time-format-for-jquery), which doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: string contains only time format "12:30AM" without space between time and AM/PM. how to get hours, minutes , am/pm USING REGEX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex to "get" the values:

```
var time = "12:30PM",
    suffix = time.substr(-2),
    numbers = time.substr(0, time.length-2);
```

Results:

```
console.log(suffix);  // "PM"
console.log(numbers); // "12:30"
```

If you want the hours / minutes in separate variables:

```
var temp = numbers.split(':'),
    hours = parseInt(temp[0], 10),   // 12
    minutes = parseInt(temp[1], 10); // 30
```

Comment: how to get hours and minutes separately

Comment: can u give it fully and what is ,10 used for

Comment: _"give it fully"_? `10` is the radix parameter for [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters), this makes sure that the first parameter is interpreted as a decimal number.

Comment: No, `.substr(-2)` returns the last 2 character from that string. In this case, `"PM"`;

Comment: so it is different from substring method

Comment: A little, indeed. But did you get the desired results out of my answer?