# Live filter user input to defined pattern with JavaScript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a particular date and time format I'm trying to live filter in the text field so the users (ideally) can't enter a different format.

On the live filtering, I've been able to limit the characters they can enter, but no luck enforcing the pattern as they type.  I know there must be some way to do this with raw JavaScript, I've tried looping over it but so far no luck.

The format that I'm using is **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm am|pm** with the time section and leading 0s being optional.  So **03/01/1982 3:14 PM** would fit, but so would **3/1/1982**  The pattern that I've devised (and tested at regex101) seems overly complicated, perhaps that's part of why I'm not having any luck.

Here is the JavaScript I have that works for controlling what can be input, though as stated it doesn't conform the input to the pattern:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function format_date(e){

    var text = document.getElementById(e);
    var regex = /[^\d pam//:]/gi;
    text.value=text.value.replace(regex, "");

}

</script>
```

and the HTML field calling it:

```
<input type="text"  id="dob" name="dob" onKeyup="formate_date('dob')" onKeydown="format_date('dob')">
```

This seems to be the regex for the pattern I need, allowing for what is optional and accounting for missing leading zeros:

```
/^[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{4}(\s[\d]{1,2}:[\d]{1,2} (am|pm))?/gi
```

Can anyone point me to examples or docs that address this type of issue or help me understand what I'm missing?  When I've tried including a loop in the function it either throws an error or doesn't enforce the pattern so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: *no luck enforcing the pattern as they type* - this is not trivial, but here is an example: to match `abc` as you type, you need `a(?:b(?:c)?)?` pattern.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful to you? Then please upvote & accept.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by Wiktor, it is not trivial to validate text input as it is typed, e.g. see this lengthy [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205164/validate-html-text-input-as-its-typed) for further insights.

However, it can be done.

I follow the approach to listen to the `propertychange` event to catch all input (directly from the keyboard or pasted text) to the `input` form field and validate the input in two steps:

1. a preliminary input as it is typed: ensures the basic format and let only values of certain type pass

   I use this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/aphz79/2):
   `(\d{0,2}(?:\/\d{0,2}(?:\/\d{0,4})?)?)(?:\s\d{0,2}(?::\d{0,2}(?:\s([APap]?[Mm]?)?)?)?)?$`
2. accepted input: input is fully validated against the allowed date time format

   The next thing is you need a much more sophisticated regex to validate the date time entry. Drawing from

   - [Regex to match Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978510/regex-to-match-date) (actually: [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and
   - [Regex for AM PM time format for jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820372/regex-for-am-pm-time-format-for-jquery)

I came up with the following gargantuan [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/RQtPES/1):

`^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:(?: (0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][Mm])|$)`

Sample code:

```js
var goodDateTime = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(?:(?: (0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d) [APap][Mm])|$)/;
var goodEntry = /^(\d{0,2}(?:\/\d{0,2}(?:\/\d{0,4})?)?)(?:\s\d{0,2}(?::\d{0,2}(?:\s([APap]?[mM]?)?)?)?)?$/;

$("input")
  .data("oldValue", "")
  .bind("input propertychange", function() {
var $this = $(this);
var newValue = $this.val();

if (!goodEntry.test(newValue))
    return $this.val($this.data("oldValue"));
if (goodDateTime.test(newValue))
    $this.removeClass("redborder");
else $this.addClass("redborder");

return $this.data("oldValue", newValue);
  });
```

```css
.redborder { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

The input box shows a red boarder if the current input is invalid.
Input like `03/01/1982 3:14 pm` or `03/01/82` or `17/12/2017` is accepted (you can paste it too).

PS:

- You may need to further validate the values (e.g. the allowed date range, etc).
- I'd also recommend to separate date and time to two different fields to make the validation easier.
- Furthermore, consider splitting the input into day, month, year, etc and test all individual parts.